# How to use a foreign key in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, android-sqlite

I have two tables in sqlite, which are "connected" with an id. The app using this tables is running on Android OS.

Table 1;:

```
|id| entry 1| entry2|
|1 | aaaaaa | aaaaa |
|2 | bbbbbb | bbbbb |
```

Table 2:

```
|id| entryx| constant|
|1 | aaaaa | aaaaaaaa|
|1 | baaaa | baaaaaaa|
|1 | caaaa | caaaaaaa|
|2 | ababa | baabaaba|
```

At the moment I delete entries with the following query, by using a loop:

```
do{
    db.delete("Table 1","id='"+cid+"'",null);
    db.delete("Table 2","id='"+cid+"'",null);
  }
while(getNextID());
```

I want to use a foreign key, which allows me to delete the entry in table 1 and all entries in table 2 are deleted as well. Besides, I have to consider that the data in table 1 are inserted, before they are inserted in table 2. How can I use a foreign key to do this? The table is using id as int and it is the primary key, the same is used for the second table.

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html in Table2 `id INTEGER REFERENCES Table1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As selvin suggested use on delete cascade

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id PRIMARY KEY  
 ,entry1 text,entry2 text
);
```

Then

```
insert into table1 values(1,"aaaa","aaaaa");
insert into table1 values(2,"bbbb","bbbbb");
```

Table2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
  id int references table1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, entryx text, constant text
);


insert into table2 values(1,"aaaa","aaaaa");
insert into table2 values(1," baaaa ","baaaaaaa");
insert into table2 values(1,"  caaaa ","caaaaaaa")
insert into table2 values(2,"bbbb","bbbbb");
```

Tables after entry

```
sqlite> select * from table1;
id          entry1      entry2    
----------  ----------  ----------
1           aaaa        aaaaa     
2           bbbb        bbbbb     
sqlite> select * from table2;
id          entryx      constant  
----------  ----------  ----------
1           aaaa        aaaaa      
1           baaaa       baaaaaaa  
1           caaaa       caaaaaaa  
2           bbbb        bbbbb
```

Delete

```
sqlite> delete from table1 where id=1;
```

Tables after delete

```
sqlite> select * from table2;
id          entryx      constant  
----------  ----------  ----------
2           bbbb        bbbbb     


sqlite> select * from table1;
id          entry1      entry2    
----------  ----------  ----------
2           bbbb        bbbbb
```

Comment: well explained!